# I'm having confusion about if-statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a condition in  javascript like this :

```
var a = '60';
var b = '500';

if(a < b) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

but the result is false, my expectation should be true, but i tried to compare with php code :

```
<?php 

  $a = '60';
  $b = '501';

  if($a < $b) {
    echo 'true';
  } else {
    echo 'false';
  }

?>
```

and the result is true, if in javascript there is no else if condition it will automatically read to the false condition if the value is not true?

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The if-else statement is correct, but the variables are not set correctly.

You can use var, but you should use let or const. (but that is just a semantic thing)

The REAL reason you are having issues is that you are putting your numbers as strings..so literally, '60' is not less than '500'.

`var a = 60;
var b = 500;`

in this case it would come out true. 60 is, in fact, less then 500 =).

Keep up the good work.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help.

Comment: I answered the same thing 9 minutes faster? Oh well. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

If you're expecting `a` and `b` to behave like numbers, don't put them in quotes. That makes them strings.

```
var a = 60;
var b = 500;
```

PHP automatically converts those to a number. Try running `echo $a - 1;` You'll get `59`. Also try `"00001" == "1"`. You'll get true! JavaScript doesn't do this kind of detection. Instead JavaScript compares strings alphabetically by their [char codes](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp). By alphabetically, I mean that it compares the first characters of each string. If they have the same char codes, it moves on to the next character of each string. If one has a higher char code than the other, it is "greater" than the other string- much like we do when we're determining if "dog" or "dot" comes first alphabetically. In this case, JavaScript would see that `6` has a char code of `54`, and `5` has a char code of `53`, and it would conclude right then and there that `"60"` is greater than `"500"`.

Comment: but in php code the result is true, can you explain for me?

Answer (score 2):

PHP converts both strings to numbers before comparing them. If you want the same in JavaScript, use:

```
if (parseInt(a, 10) < parseInt(b, 10)) {
```

This is [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is [converted to a number](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is `===` or `!==` as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid adding quotes in numbers but in case it is present there then you
can convert to number using `parseInt`.

Try this:

```js
var a = '60';
var b = '500';

if(parseInt(a) < parseInt(b)) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: but in php code the result is true, can you explain for me?

Answer (score 0):

this is not the case Javascript supports if,else if and else statements but in your code you have declared the values as strings so the compiler is not comparing the strings directly so you have to pass your variables a and b to "Number" function of javascript which will convert strings to integer.

```
var a = '60';
var b = '500';
var aint = Number(a);
var bint = Number(b);

if(aint < bint) {
  console.log('true');
} 
else if(aint>bint){
    console.log('a is greater');
  }else {
  console.log('false');
}

Output: true
```